# Android: jQuery slider not shown correctly in WebView

Tags: android, jquery, android-webview, jquery-slider

Hi I programmed a RSS reader for Android. Sometimes the feed includes a jQuery slider (RoyalSlider http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/) and this one is not shown in my webview.

My webview is initialized like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize views after the activity is created
    TextView title = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView author = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.author);
    TextView date = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.date);
    WebView wv = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.desc);

    // Enable the vertical fading edge (by default it is disabled)
    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) getView().findViewById(R.id.sv);
    sv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);


    // Set webview properties
    WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
    //to show only one column, so that picture is always scaled correctly
    ws.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    ws.setAllowContentAccess(true); 

    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    Log.d("debug","In ItemDetailFragment mit Position: "+fPos+"und Feed: "+fFeed);

    //put in data
    title.setText(fFeed.getItem(fPos).getTitle());
    author.setText(fFeed.getItem(fPos).getAuthor());
    date.setText(fFeed.getItem(fPos).getDate());
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/jquery-1.10.2.min.js", fFeed
            .getItem(fPos).getDescription(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

}
```

The slider in the RSS feed looks like this (just replaced the links to the images):

```
<p><div id="royalslider-77" class="royalSlider default" style="width:620px; height:340px;"><ul class="royalSlidesContainer"><li data-src="http://www.test.de/1.jpg" class="royalSlide"></li><li data-src="http://www.test.de/2.jpg" class="royalSlide"></li><li data-src="http://www.test.de/3.jpg" class="royalSlide"></li><li data-src="http://www.test.de/4.jpg" class="royalSlide"></li><li data-src="http://www.test.de/5.jpg" class="royalSlide"></li></ul></div><script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery("#royalslider-77").royalSlider({"width":620,"height":340,"skin":"default","preloadSkin":false,"lazyLoading":true,"preloadNearbyImages":true,"slideshowEnabled":false,"slideshowDelay":5000,"slideshowPauseOnHover":true,"slideshowAutoStart":true,"keyboardNavEnabled":false,"dragUsingMouse":true,"slideSpacing":0,"startSlideIndex":0,"imageAlignCenter":true,"imageScaleMode":"fit","autoScaleSlider":false,"autoScaleSliderWidth":620,"autoScaleSliderHeight":700,"slideTransitionType":"move","slideTransitionSpeed":400,"slideTransitionEasing":"easeInOutSine","directionNavEnabled":true,"directionNavAutoHide":false,"hideArrowOnLastSlide":true,"controlNavigationType":"none","auto-generate-images":false,"auto-generate-thumbs":false,"thumb-width":60,"thumb-height":60,"captionAnimationEnabled":true,"captionShowFadeEffect":true,"captionShowMoveEffect":"movetop","captionMoveOffset":20,"captionShowSpeed":400,"captionShowEasing":"easeInOutSine","captionShowDelay":200,"controlNavEnabled":false,"captionShowEffects":["fade","movetop"]});});</script><br />
```

It looks like this in my webview, first the text and the slider is only represented as these four dots:

[image]

Anyone an idea where my mistake is?

Comment: What version of android are you using?

Comment: Looks to me like the JavaScript or CSS for the slider isn't getting loaded correctly. The call to loadDataWithBaseUrl doesn't look right. Why is the js file the base URL? What does the data look like?

Comment: Can you try inserting a script tag into the data that links to the JS file, instead of using it as the base URL?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.test.de/1.jpg link is broken - gives a 404

Check if all the other referenced URLs are rendering.

Unless the URL is working I see the list bullets that you are receiving is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
// set web chrome client by adding this in ur on create    
wv.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebViewChromeClient());

  // this is web chrome client implemetation. it works. Any issues please put comments. i got   working
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return false;
  } 

  @Override
  public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
 {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
  }

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onPageFinished(view, url);
 }

   @TargetApi(11)
   @Override
   public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
   Log.d("shouldInterceptRequest", url);

    InputStream stream = inputStreamForAndroidResource(url);
    if (stream != null) {
       return new WebResourceResponse("text/javascript", "utf-8", stream);
   }
   return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
}

private InputStream inputStreamForAndroidResource(String url) {
   final String ANDROID_ASSET = "file:///android_asset/";

   if (url.contains(ANDROID_ASSET)) {
       url = url.replaceFirst(ANDROID_ASSET, "");
       try {
           AssetManager assets = getAssets();
           Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
           return assets
                   .open(uri.getPath(), AssetManager.ACCESS_STREAMING);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   return null;
}
}
```